# How does a complete check function work in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, destructure

I'm making a todo list and I don't really understand this whole complete check function, like where does the *item* come from and so...can anybody help me to explain! Thank you so much for helping me!

This is the function:

```
const handleComplete = (todo) => {
    setTodos(
        todos.map((item) => {
            if(item.id === todo.id){
                return {...item, completed: !item.completed}
            }
            return item
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Array.prototype.map()` is a function that creates and returns a new array filled with elements being the results of the function called on each element on the array:

```
//[array] [element]     [transformed  element inserted in result array]
//  |        |                               |
//  v        v                               v
todos.map((item) => ({...item, completed: !item.completed}));
```

So whatever your `todos` array holds as items, the returned result that will be passed as an argument to `setTodos` will be an array of `{...item, completed: !item.completed}` elements each.

You can read more about the `Array.prototype.map()` function in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Note that this is pure *Javascript* and has nothing to do with *React* or any other framework / library.

Answer (score 0):

As Your code suggests, you are trying to update a single item from your list of todos elements, so when your `handleComplete` function is called, a todo object is passed, so in the `setTodos` function, with the help of the map first we find the item from collection of todos which matches with id of passed todo object.

If found, we will return an object, `...item` it helps to preserve all the elements present in the item object and only update the `complete` key.

Answer (score 0):

`todos` is an array and every array has a `map` function which iterates on the array and  is used to modify the items in a array. So `item` is representing the current `item` of the array. You can name it anything.

In this function , you are setting the state of `todos` using the `setTodos`. Here we are checking that if `item.id` is equal to `todo.id` then set the state of `todos`.

And while setting the state , we are preserving the initial state of `todos` by using this  `return {...item, completed: !item.completed}`

Three dots before `item` is called destructuring.

[Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

[Map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)